# What is the easiest way to get an usb-drive unique id with python on linux?

Tags: python, usb, usb-drive

I want to get the unique id from an usb hard-drive with python for a project im working on. What is the easiest way of achieving this? Is there a better way to do it? Can this be done platform independent?

Comment: to begin with i want it to work on ubuntu linux, but it would be nice to have it work on mac and pc as well later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the system call to read in 'lsusb', and then parse the output.

```
import os  
cmd = 'lsusb'  
os.system(cmd)
```

Or an easier to parse solution would be the commands library.

```
import commands  
output = commands.getstatusoutput('lsusb')
```

And then you would manipulate or search output with regex for your device.

Comment: Brilliant!! and this should work on windows and mac also, i would just have to detect which os is running and alter the command accordingly!